# The indefinite article with the word "conversation"

Tags: articles

Is the use of the indefinite article in the following sentence optional?

> "This makes for (an) excellent conversation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's optional whether to include the indefinite article ***an*** before ***conversation*** in OP's exact context.

I can't really see much scope for a difference in meaning, nor is it obvious to me that either version is any more likely than the other. But in other contexts there could be a difference. Consider...

> 1: *Yesterday I had conversation with Tom, Dick, and Harry.*
>    2: *Yesterday I had **a** conversation with Tom, Dick, and Harry.*

...where in #2 the speaker is explicitly stating that he had one single conversation in which all the named people participated. But #1 could also reasonably be used if there had been several conversations, each involving one or more of those people (i.e. - the speaker could just as validly have used the plural form ***conversations***).

---

Note that in my *specific* example, the article-less usage *to **have** conversation with X* is a relatively formal/dated construction (we'd more likely use *to **engage in** conversation with X* today). I don't think that nuance really applies to OP's context, so the only real difference is that article-less *This makes for interesting conversation* might in some circumstances imply multiple conversations (perhaps significantly different *types* of conversation), whereas including the article implies a single conversation (or feasibly, multiple conversations of a very similar nature).